# Display search results dynamically as typing

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to build a SharePoint 2007 web part in Visual Studio.
This web part should search a sharepoint list and display the results.

What I want to accomplish is to display the results as soon as the user stops typing, so no clicking button involved.

Probably, a combination of text_changed event and onkeydown javascript?

Any thought would be great.

This sharepoint site is "Ajax-enabled", btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using jquery and keyup:

```
$("input#txtid").keyup(function () {
                if (this.value.length < 8)
                    return false;

                $.get("ServiceUrl", { arg: this.value }, function (result) { $("#output").html(result); });

            });
```

Comment: +1 but use `keydown` and also `change`.  Remember that the user can use mouse techniques to alter the search term (cut, paste, spelling-correct, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to take care of the UI part is to use the AjaxToolkit AutoCompleteExtender se [MOSS, AJAX and the AutoCompleteExtender](http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2007/07/08/moss-ajax-and-the-autocompleteextender/) then all you have to do is decide how you want the searching inside the web service to work

Answer (score 0):

I approached this by using an `UpdatePanel` in my webpart. Then I added a Button (more on this later) and a TextBox to the UpdatePanel.

I also have a JavaScript class which handles all of the logic for submitting a query after the user has paused while typing their query. It contains the event handler for the `onkeyup` event which is attached to the TextBox:

`t.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "javascript:oSearchClass.KeyUpEventHandler(event);");`

I used [setTimeout and clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to handle when the class should call a `SubmitQuery` function.

When `SubmitQuery()` is called, it makes the TextBox read only (so the user can't type anything while it is querying) and then "clicks" the button using `click()`. Since you're using a normal Button, you can handle the Button.click event like normal to re-query the list and display results.

If you don't want your user to see the button, you can simply put it inside a `span` WebControl that is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample, it adds 'search as you type' to the standard SharePoint search box.

[Automatically add ‘Search As You Type’ to every SharePoint page using Infuser](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/07/automatically-add-search-as-you-type-to.html).